# How to add/remove layers of background-images depending on the section in the same page

Tags: css

As a background I have a linear gradient and a background texture image in combination, like this:

```css
background-image: url("TEXTURE_IMG_URL"), linear-gradient(
rgba(2, 0, 36, 1) 0%,
rgba(25, 147, 150, 1) 35%,
rgba(117, 144, 141, 1) 100%);
```

I don't want the `TEXTURE_IMG` in all the sections as it can overlap the text but I want to keep the `linear-gradient` background all over the page.
**How can I add an extra layer of background-image (texture) to a particular section, so I keep having my linear gradient as background and only the background texture image combined at the section I want?**

Styling combined background-image separately for each section doesn't work because it breaks the color progression of the linear gradient which I want in all the page from top to bottom.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

1. CSS allows you to add multiple background images for an element,through the background-image property.
2. The different background images are separated by commas, and the images are stacked on top of each other, where the first image is closest to the viewer.
3. The following example has two background images, the first image is a flower and the second image is a paper background.

```html
<html>
<head>
<style> 
#example1 {
  background-image: url(img_flwr.gif), url(paper.gif);
  background-position: right bottom, left top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
  padding: 15px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>Multiple Backgrounds</h1>
<p>Two background image</p>

<div id="example1">
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum Dolor</h1>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.</p>
  <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: But in this case I want to keep the gradient background for the whole body section and only set both, previous gradient background and texture image combined in a particular section...

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh thanksssssssssss jahnavi it will work for me.